# VB.net Chart Series Names - Error When Using Loop

Tags: charts, series

I am using a loop to add series to a chart based on column name

With ds.Tables("MyTable")

```
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            For Each column As DataColumn In .Columns

                If column.ColumnName Like "S1_*" Then

                    Chart2.Series.Add(column.ColumnName)

                    Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).YValueMembers = column.ColumnName

                    Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

                    Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).BorderWidth = 3

                    Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).XValueMember = .Columns("DateTime").ToString

                    Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).IsXValueIndexed = True

                End If

             Next
```

When changing the series names manually everything works fine

With Chart2

```
  .Series(0).Name = "Series Name 1"

  .Series(1).Name = "Series Name 2"

  .Series(2).Name = "Series Name 3"
```

End With

The problem occurs when i change the way the series names are changed. If i change the series names within a loop

For i = 0 To ds.Tables("Qs").Rows.Count - 1

```
           For x = 0 To Chart2.Series.Count - 1

               If Chart2.Series(x).Name = ds.Tables("Qs").Rows(x).Item("Q_Name") Then

                   Chart2.Series(x).Name = ds.Tables("Qs").Rows(x).Item("Q_Text")



               End If

           Next
```

Next

I get the following error when viewing the chart

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll

Additional information: Cannot display indexed series (XValueIndexed = true) on the same axis if they are not aligned.A chart element with the name 'Series Name 1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

The Series names are being updated correctly within in the loop and i can see teh chart if I remove the Chart2.Series(column.ColumnName).IsXValueIndexed = True. The only difference I can see is how the series names are being changed.

All help / comments are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic starts indexing at 1. Try replacing
`.Series(0).Name = "Series Name 1"`
with
`.Series(1).Name = "Series Name 1"`
and likewise for the other series.